# How to do Division of two fixed point 64 bits variables in Synthesizable Verilog?

Tags: math, verilog, synthesis

I'm implementing an Math equation in verilog, in a combinational scheme (assigns = ...) to the moment Synthesis tool (Quartus II) has been able to do add, sub and mul easly 32 bit unsigned absolute numbers by using the operators "+,- and *" respectively.

However, one of the final steps of the equation is to divide two 64 bits unsigned fixed point variables, the reason why is such of large 64 bit capacity is because I'm destinating 16 bits for integers and 48 bits for fractions (although, computer does everything in binary and doesn't care about fractions, I would be able to check the number to separate fraction from integer in the end).

Problem is that the operator "/" is useless since it auto-invokes a so-called "LPM_divide" library which output only gives me the integer, disregarding fractions, plus in a wrong position (the less significant bit).

For example:

b1000111010000001_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 / b1000111010000001_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

should be 1, it gives me

b0000000000000000_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

So, how can I make this division for synthesizable verilog? What methods or algorithms should I follow, I'd like it to be faster, maybe a full combinational? 
I'd like it to keep the 16 integers - 24 fractions user point of view.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume you multiply two fixed-point numbers.
Let's call them X and Y, first containing Xf fractional bits, and second Yf fractional bits accordingly.
If you multiply those numbers as integers, the LSB Xf+Yf bits of the integer result could be treated as fractional bits of resulting fixed-point number (and you still multiply them as integers).

Similarly, if you divide number of Sf fractional bits by number of Df fractional bits, the resulting integer could be treated as fixed-point number having Sf-Df fractional bits -- therefore your example with resulting integer 1.

Thus, if you need to get 48 fractional bits from your division of 16.48 number by another 16.48 number, append divident with another 48 zeroed fractional bits, then divide the resulting 64+48=112-bit number by another 64-bit number, treating both as integers (and using LPM_divide). The result's LSB 48 bits will then be what you need -- the resulting fixed-point number's 48 fractional bits.

Comment: so your example transforms to 1000111010000001_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 / b1000111010000001_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 0000000000000001_000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Thanks lvd, it works nice, although cause LPM_divide won't accept +64 operands, instead of adding to 112 bits, I decided to truncate the denominator to 32 bits (while numerator remains 64) so it could fill into the LPM_divide, the result has good enough precision. I wish to know more in detail what LPM_divide does in its algorithm, you taught me how it works but for learning more (i'm new in verilog) I wish to study how LPM_divide does this, how should I looked it internet? does it have a particular algorithm name?

Comment: Try this links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_.28unsigned.29_with_remainder , https://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/divide.030.html .

Comment: I would recommend you to implement your own division algos in HDL, since inner structure of LPM_divide is almost impossible to reverse engineer.